# How to combine multiple dicts, summing the values of common keys (and retaining those with value 0) in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, iteration, defaultdict

Given three dicts d1, d2 and d3:

**d1**

```
{'a':1,'b':2,'c':3, 'd':0)
```

**d2**

```
{'b':76}
```

**d3**

```
{'a': 45, 'c':0}
```

There are some key names that are common to more than one dict (and in reality, they will represent the same real-life object). Others such as 'd' in d1 only exist in d2. I want to group all dicts together, **first summing the values of the common keys first,** ending up with:

```
{'a':46, 'b':78, 'c':3, 'd': 0}
```

If every dict were the same size and contained the same keys, I could do something like:

```
summedAndCombined = {}
    for k,v in d1.items():
        summedAndCombined[k] = d1[k]+d2[k]+d3[k]
```

But this will break down as soon as it reaches a key that is in d1 but not in the others. How do we achieve this?

### UPDATE

**Not a duplicate. collections.Counter *almost* works, but the key *d* is missing from the resulting Counter if the value of key d is zero, which it is above.**

```
In [128]: d1 = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3, 'd':0}

In [129]: d2 = {'b':76}

In [130]: d3 = {'a': 45, 'c':0}

In [131]: from collections import Counter

In [132]: Counter(d1) + Counter(d2) + Counter(d3)
Out[132]: Counter({'b': 78, 'a': 46, 'c': 3})
```

Comment: `if k in d2.keys() ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `update` instead of `+` with `Counter` if you want the 0 keys to persist:

```
>>> c = Counter()
>>> for d in d1, d2, d3:
...     c.update(d)
...     
>>> c
Counter({'b': 78, 'a': 46, 'c': 3, 'd': 0})
```

(This is probably a dup, but I can't find it right now.)

Answer (score 2):

`collections.defaultdict` to the rescue

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(int)
for thing in [d1, d2, d3]:
    for k, v in thing.items():
        d[k] += v
```

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED:

```
def merge_dicts(*dicts):
    res = {}
    for key in set(sum(map(list, dicts), [])):
        res[key] = 0
        for dct in dicts:
            res[key] += dct.get(key, 0)
    return res
```

Example usage:

```
merge_dicts(d1, d2, d3)
```